# How to find out the right citation style?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am trying to find out which citation style fits my demands best for my bibliography.

As I am writing for a german science institution and using many german sources, I intented using `jurabib`

My bibliography should look like this:

- Harding, Leonhard. 1994. Einführung in das Studium der Afrikanischen
  Geschichte, 2.überarb. Aufl., Studien zur Afrikanischen Geschichte,
  Bd. 4. Münster u.a.: Lit.
- Deutsch, Jan-Georg und Albert Wirz (Hg.). 1997. Geschichte in Afrika. Einführung in Probleme und Debatten, Zentrum Moderner Orient Studien 7. Berlin: Das Arabische Buch.

So far I end up with the following:

- Treichel, Dietmar/Mayer, Claude-Hélène: Lehrbuch Kultur: Lehr- und
  Lernmaterialien zur Vermittlung kultureller Kompetenzen. Waxmann,
  September 2011, ISBN 383092531X.

What would be your advice for my specific case? And more generally: When having a set style of citation, how can I find the corresponding citation style for bibtex?

Comment: I would suggest that you drop jurabib +bibtex, which is a pain to adapt, and use biblatex + biber instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the institution does not provide you with a citation style file, you may try to replicate the information setup with `makebst`. On any terminal just type `latex makebst` and follow the steps. It's a succession of questions-answers about how you want your bibliography to look like. The result is a your.bst file which you can then use in any LaTeX editor.

[image: latex makebst]